# Laravel: Expecting response 250 but got "" with message ""

Tags: php, laravel, email, sendgrid

I continue to get this error from Laravel, but everything looks correct:

```
Expecting response 250 but got "" with message ""
```

From what I've been able to research, the problem occurs when sending email through Sendgrid (or any provider) and the receiving server responds with a blank code.

Instead of passing along the blank code, SendGrid translates it into this; Sendgrid expects the 250 (every thing is okay) code, but gets nothing.

I don't know how to fix this. I've come across a couple solutions, but they didn't work.

For those who are interested, here is the code that sends the email via a controller:

```
        if ($circle->business)
        {
            $email = $circle->creator->email;
            $name = $circle->creator->fullName();
        }
        else
        {
            $email = $user->email;
            $name = $user->fullName();
        }

        Mail::send('layouts.'.$this->client->template->file.'.views.emails.transaction-receipt', compact('user'), function($message) use($user)
        {
            $message->from($user->account->email, $user->account->name);
            $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject($user->account->name.' Transaction Receipt');
        });
```

Comment: Where/when do you get the error message?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem because my SendGrid password was incorrect.

If your credentials are incorrect SendGrid doesn't send a response.